# AvalonDock - How to forbid pull-out of the floating element of the window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, avalondock

i would like to ask if it is possible to forbid pull-out of the floating element of the window.

In AvalonDock in WPF

Thanks

Comment: please specify "forbid pull out". "pull out" from where? to where? what do you mean by "floating element of the window"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ad:DockingManager>
    <ad:ResizingPanel>
        <ad:DocumentPane>
            <ad:DocumentContent IsCloseable="False" IsFloatingAllowed="False">
                  .........
```